# All mail going from my VPS are rejected

Tags: smtp, hosting, vps

I've VPS and it was working good with no problem but after 2 or 3 days all mails from the server are getting rejected. I've added rDNS as with my server ip and mail.server.com .. but no luck.
what am i missing?

my server mail.emanupload.com

Comment: Wrong place for this, as it's not programming-related. Maybe ask on SuperUser?

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server IP has most likely been blacklisted.

Check your mail server IP using the below link:

https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

You should also consider checking your recipient email address using the below to make sure the email address is actually valid:

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/demo

For more possible reasons why your emails are not getting through, read the following:

https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/resources/articles/why-are-my-emails-bouncing-back/

Comment: If it's blacklisted the mail would go to spam folder but it's getting rejected

Comment: If your mail server IP is blacklisted, some ISPs may reject all emails coming from that IP.

Comment: The problem as "mxtoolbox" is the i don't have PTR record and I don't know how to add it :(

Comment: Adding PTR record is something similar to the steps in http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/managed-dns/dns-record-types/ptr-record/ but you will have to check with your hosting provider for their specific steps.